# Passing installation path via command line - installshield

Tags: c#, installation, installshield

I have this installation file setup.exe that was created with installShield wizard.
as part of the installation the user needs to prompt the installation path,
now i don't have any access to the installshield environment i can only run the setup.exe
file.
I want to activate the installation process via the command line in silent mode,and i need
a way to transfer to the setup.exe (via command line arguments) the installation path.
is there any way for me to do so ?? (msi installtion enables this option)

Thanks,
Liran

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends mostly upon what kind of installation is behind the setup.exe you are installing.  If it's a Basic MSI, you can pass MSI properties within a /v"..." parameter, and chances are good passing /v"/qn INSTALLDIR=*{path}*" will be what you want. However if it's an InstallScript project, you'll need to record a .iss file, and include it to run silently.

See http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield15helplib/IHelpSetup_EXECmdLine.htm for details.